# Getting Exponential value from Excel column

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, exponential

I created a function that reads an Excel sheet. So there is a field in the sheet that contains a value of `0.01`, but when I read this value it change into some exponential form like this `1.2999999999999999E-2`, so it throws exception when I pass the value to the datatable.

How can this value be read accuratly **OR** avoided in code?

Here is my code to read the Excel sheet -

```
        using (var sDoc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(FileName, false))
        {

            bool emptyTable = false;

            var sheets = sDoc.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<Sheets>().Elements<Sheet>();
            var relationshipId = sheets.First().Id.Value;
            var worksheetPart = (WorksheetPart)sDoc.WorkbookPart.GetPartById(relationshipId);
            var workSheet = worksheetPart.Worksheet;
            var sheetData = workSheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();
            var rows = sheetData.Descendants<Row>().Skip(IgnoreRows).ToList();

            if (rows.Count == 0)
            {
                Results = dt;
                emptyTable = true;
            }

            if (!emptyTable)
            {
                foreach (var cell in rows.ElementAt(0).Cast<Cell>())
                {
                    dt.Columns.Add(GetCellValue(sDoc, cell));
                }

                foreach (var row in rows.Skip(1))
                {
                    bool emptyRow = true;
                    var tempRow = dt.NewRow();

                    for (var i = 0; i < row.Descendants<Cell>().Count(); i++)
                    {
                        string rowValue = GetCellValue(sDoc, row.Descendants<Cell>().ElementAt(i));
                        tempRow[i] = rowValue;
                        emptyRow = emptyRow && String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(rowValue);
                    }

                    if (!emptyRow)
                    {
                        dt.Rows.Add(tempRow);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

And here is the exception value: 
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this (code block inside your `for` loop)

```
string rowValue = GetCellValue(sDoc, row.Descendants<Cell>().ElementAt(i));

if (i == 5) // index of column where you're expecting that value
{
    decimal tempDecimal;
    decimal.TryParse(rowValue, NumberStyles.AllowExponent | NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out tempDecimal);
    rowValue = tempDecimal.ToString("0.##");
}
tempRow[i] = rowValue;
emptyRow = emptyRow && String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(rowValue)
```

Basically, code is trying to parse value from specific column (5 in my example) to decimal and then converts it back to string with two decimal points.