# convert to string failed, input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, excel

How can I convert decimal numbers into string in a correct?

In excel, the value in abc sheet is `0.00000079`, and I want to store it in string format by the following code:

```
string abc = Convert.ToString(abcSheet.Cells[1, 14].Value);
```

but I receive the number like `7.9E-05`, this is not what I want. I want the abc can store exactly `0.00000079`.

However, I also try the method from google:

```
double abc0 = Convert.ToDouble(abcSheet.Cells[1, 14].Value);
string abc = abc0.ToString("0." + new string('#', 339));
```

Unluckily, I got an error:

```
System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Number.ParseDouble(String value, NumberStyles options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt)
   at System.Convert.ToDouble(String value)
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Type , Object )
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute2[T0,T1,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1)
```

I quite new to c# , I don't know how to solve this problem...Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45433663/getting-exponential-value-from-excel-column

Comment: "convert to string failed" - no, `Convert.ToDouble` failed. That's *parsing* a string, not *formatting* it.

Comment: abc stores exactly 0.00000079. 7.9E-05 is just a different representation of the same number. By default C# will prefer the shorter version when actually displaying the number. This can be overriden like you're doing with the google answer. There's multiple formatting strings you can use https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings . See this repl for examples https://replit.com/@domjancik/StringFormatting#main.cs And as mentioned, the error is in converting the excel value to Double. Print out the excel value and see what's wrong with it.